# A deceased person as a subject in a present perfect sentence

Tags: present-perfect

Is it correct to use The Present Perfect when we want to say that a person **who died in the past** (has) taught us something?

> My grandfather has taught me that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plato is more famous than OP's grandfather, so it's easier to find [example usages...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Plato%20teaches%20us%2CPlato%20taught%20us%2CPlato%20has%20taught%20us&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPlato%20teaches%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPlato%20taught%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPlato%20has%20taught%20us%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Note that the Present Perfect form will tend to carry a slightly different nuance - it puts more emphasis on *our present state of knowledge*, rather than Plato's pedagogic activities. So although it's less common overall, you might choose it specifically for that nuance.

---

In case it's not obvious, all three are perfectly "correct" both syntactically and idiomatically.

Comment: So, if the grandfather who died in the past taught me a rule which I follow, it's better to emphasise that fact to use the Present Perfect?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that "Plato" and "OP's grandfather" are comparable. Being an Ancient, "Plato" is on par with "science" or "mathematics" or *The Prince* as a general subject of knowledge. I would not at all say that "my grandfather has taught me..." is correct if the grandfather is dead, and even if he was alive it's not the first construction I would use. Instead I would use "my grandfather taught me..."

Comment: I originally charted ***Jesus** teaches / has taught us*, but I decided that was confusing because some people would claim Jesus is "timeless" and/or "still alive". The problem with searching for [***grandfather** has taught me*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22grandfather+has+taught+me%22) is it's hard to see whether the subject is still alive at time of utterance. But that's a link to an awful lot of written instances, and even on the first page I see *The first lesson that my **great - great - grandfather** has taught me is that people are made of hardy stuff*. And *he's* dead!

Comment: @piter00: As a rule, non-native Anglophones tend to overuse Perfect verb forms anyway. I'm adamant that syntactically / logically there's nothing actually *wrong* with using it in your context, but my basic position here is *You **can** use it, but I advise not.*